# Dispersion relation in string vibration

Tags: waves, string, vibrations, dispersion

In case of a continuous,bounded string we know, the dispersion relation is linear, i.e, the restoring force is directly proportional with the wave propagation vector. In other words,

$$w=ck$$

Where $w$ is the frequency and $k$ is the wave vector, $c$ is the wave velocity.

Or in other language the frequency corresponding to 2nd,3rd normal modes are double,triple the frequency of the 1st normal mode.

But in case of a beaded string where the number of beads is finite the dispersion relation is no more linear and it takes a form,

$$w=2x\sin{(kl/2)}$$

Where $w$ is the frequency corresponding to wave vector $k$, $x$ is the frequency of the first normal mode and $l$ is the separation between successive beads.

It implies that the frequency corresponding to say 2nd or 3rd normal mode is not the double or triple of the 1st one.

Now under continuous approximation the second case certainly leads to the first case but what happens physically so that the restoring force for say 2nd mode is double of 1st mode in continuous case and not double in the finite no of beads case?

Comment: Are you talking about "string theory" here? For a wire under tension, your statement "the frequency corresponding to any normal mode is double the frequency of the previous normal mode" is wrong - the modes have frequencies f, 2f, 3f, 4f, etc not f, 2f, 4f, 8f, etc.

Comment: Mistakenly wrote that,edited now